# Send JSON object back to PHP after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, json

This question is something that has baffled me for a while...

Let's say I have a form with the text field "customerId" and a submit button. I am using ajax to get the customers id, pass it to a php controller and pull a customers information based on their customer id. Once I get the information I Json encode the array and send it back to php.

Is it possible at this point to format my user information with php in a standard foreach loop, or is my only option to use jquery to pass the various json array keys and values back to my view?

I hope this makes sense. To clarify a bit, I would usually do this without ajax, grab an array for my user than do a foreach loop for this user and display his info. I am asking if the Json object can be passed BACK to the php somehow and used that way instead of with jquery.

Comment: Why not do all the work on the "php controller" side?  You pass the customer id to your php controller, and it can do all the work you need with your loop BEFORE it returns it via JSON encode.

Answer (score 0):

No, you unfortunately cannot simply send back the information to PHP. Once the PHP script is done, it sends the page back to browser and the script closes all the variables and all resources it used up. This is the distinction between Javasript which is the client side scripting language and PHP which is the server side scripting language. Anything that you want to happen after PHP executed has to  be handled on the client side as the page has done rendering.

- Javascript -> Executed in the browser and thus works AFTER the page has been rendered
- PHP -> Executed upon request on the server. Once once its done, the page is sent back to the browser and the script is not accessible unless you reload the page.

Comment: Well, you can use all the normal technologies for formatting like CSS. If you say return "echo <div class='myClass'></div> that div will will be formatted to that class upon rendering. (no JQuery required)